# Data type to store file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Tell me the datatype in MS SQL server to store any word/pdf file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in SQL Server to store the images or any doc types.

```
binary [ ( n ) ]
```

Fixed-length binary data with a length of n bytes, where n is a value from 1 through 8,000. The storage size is n bytes.

```
varbinary [ ( n | max) ]
```

Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in length. The ANSI SQL synonym for varbinary is binary varying.

varbinary - Newly introduced in SQL Server 2005

More info : http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10074732/upload-a-word-or-pdf-file.aspx

[Store and Retrieve PDF file](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/08/31/storing-and-retrieving-docpdfxls-files-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score -1):

It's been a long time since i've used SQL server. You should look for blob field type for storing large data or binary data. check out msdn.